# Symfony - adding additional field manually

Tags: php, function, symfony

I wrote a query to return all data from db.. Now, I need to add one additional field. The api call should receive one additional field - "term". When term is passed, results are filtered to match that term.

My Service.

```
/**
 * Return all schools from city
 *
 * @param int $limit
 * @param int $offset
 * @return array
 */
public function getCityPaginated($limit = 20, $offset = 0)
{

    $query = $this->getCityRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->getQuery();

    return $this->container->get('paginator')->paginate($query, $offset, $limit);
}
```

My Controller..

```
/**
 * @Route("/cities", name="city_list")
 * @throws \Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException
 */
public function getCityPaginatedAction()
{
    if(isset($this->data['offset'])){
        $offset = $this->data['offset'];
    }else {
        $offset = 0;
    }

    if(isset($this->data['limit'])){
        $limit = $this->data['limit'];
    }else{
        $limit = 20;
    }

    $city = $this->get('city')->getCityPaginated($limit, $offset);

    return $this->success($city, ['city_data']);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what your question is

Comment: I edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: By "The api call should receive one additional field - term"  you mean a GET, a POST param or something else?

Comment: I  meant POST param. And that additional field is not a part of an Entity.

Comment: @FilipStojanovic What exactly your term will be ? City name, school name? What?

Comment: That "term" will be something manually written. $term = 'term'...

Comment: And what ist the **exact** question? How to get the filtering term from the request? How to add it to the query? What have you tried to find a solution on your own?

Comment: Yes I want do add it to a query. I tried multiple solutions, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you need to get a POST parameter?

```
public function getCityPaginatedAction(Request $request)
{
   $term = $request->request->get('term');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller so that you read the `term` parameter from request and pass it to the service method:

```
/**
 * @Route("/cities", name="city_list")
 * @param Request $request
 * @throws \Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException
 */
public function getCityPaginatedAction(Request $request)
{
    if(isset($this->data['offset'])){
        $offset = $this->data['offset'];
    }else {
        $offset = 0;
    }

    if(isset($this->data['limit'])){
        $limit = $this->data['limit'];
    }else{
        $limit = 20;
    }

    $term = $request->query->get('term');
    $city = $this->get('city')->getCityPaginated($limit, $offset, $term);

    return $this->success($city, ['city_data']);
}
```

Then, change your service to use this parameter in the query

```
/**
 * Return all schools from city
 *
 * @param int $limit
 * @param int $offset
 * @param string $text
 * @return array
 */
public function getCityPaginated($limit = 20, $offset = 0, $term = null)
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->getCityRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('c');

    if ($term) {
        $queryBuilder->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->like('c.name', :term)
            ->setParameter('term', "%" . $term . "%");
    }

    $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();

    return $this->container->get('paginator')->paginate($query, $offset, $limit);
}
```

You may want to change the query builder and search on other fields as well.